# wrong result of counting

Tags: java

I'm writing a program which counts the total number of students in each class (music, art, theatre, sport). If i had 3 students, and two of them take the art class and one takes music class, the results should be: art -2 and music -1. I got a wrong result.

comment: the music class represent by number one and art by 2.

Results:

Insert numbers of participants:
3
Insert student in class:
2
student in class:2
Total:1
student in class:4
Total:0
Insert student in class:
2
student in class:2
Total:3
student in class:4
Total:1
Insert student in class:
1
student in class:1
Total:1
student in class:4
Total:2

My code:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class GroupActivity
{ 
    public static void main()

```
{
  Scanner GActivity=new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Insert numbers of participants:");
  int participantNo= GActivity.nextInt();//Insert numbers of participants


  int music= 1;int art=2; int theatre= 3; int sport= 4; // Representation of each class by numbers.
  int countM=0; //This variable contains the number of the participants in music class.
  int countA=0; //This variable contains the number of the participants in art class.
  int countT=0; //This variable contains the number of the participants in theatre class.
  int countS=0; //This variable contains the number of the participants in sport class.

  for(int i=0;i<participantNo;i++)
  {
         System.out.println("Insert student in class:");
         int p= GActivity.nextInt();// // Representation of student by number.

         if(p==music)
         {
            countM++;
            System.out.println("student in class:"+music);
            System.out.println("Total:"+countM++);
         }
          else if(p==art)
         {
            countA++;
            System.out.println("student in class:"+art);
            System.out.println("Total:"+countA++);
         }
          else if(p==theatre)
         {
            countT++;
            System.out.println("student in class:"+theatre);
            System.out.println("Total:"+countT++);

        }
         else
            countS++;
            System.out.println("student in class:"+sport);
            System.out.println("Total:"+countS++);
        }

    }

  }
```

Comment: what are you expecting?  also, when p == musix you increment countM twice.

Comment: I edited the code and the result

Comment: yes and blew away the formatting other folks applied to your code and results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else
    countS++;
    System.out.println("student in class:"+sport);
```

You are missing braces there! Your code effectively functions like this:

```
else {
    countS++;
}
System.out.println("student in class:"+sport);
```

Add the braces after `else` to fix the problem.

Also, as Taylor points out in the comments, you increment music class counter twice instead of once with each added student.

EDIT: because apparently just saying it wasn't clear enough, here's some code to demonstrate:

```
countS++; //countS is incremented by one
System.out.println("student in class:"+sport);
System.out.println("Total:"+countS++); //countS is incremented by one AGAIN
```

So you're getting your students doubled. However, since `countS++` evaluates to `countS` the print message appears correct for the first time you do this - but the value of `countS` is still altered resulting in the next iteration producing faulty results.

Comment: Hi, The total of student in music class should be 2 instead of 3. Where i worng in the code?

Comment: Don't increment the counters twice.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code according to your suggestion and still i get the worn results.

Comment: Can I see your current code then? Try not to break the formatting when pasting!

Comment: I have another question, each of the calsses should contain maximum 20 students. I like to count the number of room for each class, for instance, if i'v 60 students, 20-art and 40-sport, the results have to be: 1 room for art and 2 rooms for sport. How can i do that?

Comment: Yes, the white tick mark. For your another question, it's better that you open a new question instead of discussing it here.

Comment: I have another question, each of the calsses should contain maximum 20 students. I like to count the number of room for each class, for instance, if i'v 60 students, 20-art and 40-sport, the results have to be: 1 room for art and 2 rooms for sport. How can i do that?

Comment: "@Nizan I think you marked the wrong answer"- Your answer was halpful, i like to mark your answer, how am i doing that?

Answer (score 0):

don't increment things in output statements

```
System.out.println("Total:"+countS++);
```

As stated in the answer there are two increments being made one unintentionally in the print statement. It's almost always a bad idea to do this. This is why

```
 int i = 0;  // the value of i is zero
 System.out.println(i++); // prints the value zero, but the value of i is one
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how is this going to resolve the problem?